# Boost.spirit: parsing number char and string

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

I need to parse a line containing an unsigned int, the character `X` that is to be discarded, and a string, all separated by one or more spaces.  e.g., `1234 X abcd`

```
bool a = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
      uint_[ref(num) = _1] >> lit('X') >> lexeme[+(char_ - ' ')],
      space, parsed_str);
```

The above code parses the three parts, but the string ends up containing a junk character (`�abcd`) and having a size of 5 and not 4.

What is wrong with my parser? and why is there junk in the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably haven't realized, is that parser expressions stop having *automatic attribute propagation* in the presence of *semantic actions*<sup>*</sup>.

> <sup>*</sup> Documentation backgound: [How Do Rules Propagate Their Attributes?](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/01/15/how-do-rules-propagate-attributes/)

You're using a semantic action to 'manually' propagate the attribute of the `uint_` parser:

```
[ref(num) = _1]   // this is a Semantic Action
```

So the easiest way to fix this, would be to propagate `num` automatically too (the way the `qi::parse` and `qi::phrase_parse` APIs were intended):

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,               // input iterators
        uint_ >> lit('X') >> lexeme[+(char_ - ' ')],  // parser expr
        space,                                      // skipper
        num, parsed_str);                            // output attributes
```

Or, addressing some off-topic points, even cleaner:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
        uint_ >> 'X' >> lexeme[+graph],
        blank, 
        num, parsed_str);
```

As you can see, you can pass multiple lvalues as output attribute recipients.<sup>1, 2</sup>

See it a live **[demo on Coliru (link)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=97773c2c509566a004d3ca54af0e1916-76b69eb4e48bf39ce4212f2d8ff4a507)**

There's a whole lot of magic going on, which in practice leads to my rule of thumb:

> Avoid using semantic actions in Spirit Qi expressions unless you absolutely have to

I have about this before, in an answer specificly about this: [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil/8259585#8259585)

In my experience, it's almost always cleaner to use the Attribute Customization Points to tweak the *automatic* propagation than to abandon auto rules and resort to manual attribute handling.

---

<sup>1</sup> What technically happens to propagate these attributes, is that `num` and `parsed_str` will be *'tied'* to the whole parse expression as a Fusion sequence:

```
fusion::vector2<unsigned&, std::string&>
```

and the exposed attribute of the rule:

```
fusion::vector2<unsigned, std::vector<char> >
```

will be 'transformed' to that during assignment. The attribute compatibility rules allow this conversion, and many others.

---

<sup>2</sup> Alternatively, use semantic actions for both:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
        (uint_ >> 'X' >> as_string [ lexeme[+graph] ]) 
            [ phx::ref(num) = _1, phx::ref(parsed_str) = _2 ],
        blank);
```

There's a few subtleties here:

- we need `as_string` here to expose the attribute as `std::string` instead of `std::vector<char>` (see above)
- we need to qualify `phx::ref(parsed_str)` since even `using boost::phoenix::ref` will not be enough to disambiguate `std::ref` and `phx::ref`: ADL will drag in `std::ref` since it is from the same namespace as the type of `parsed_str`.
- group the semantic action to prevent partially assigned results, e.g. the following would overwrite `num` even though `X` may be missing in the input:

  ```
  bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
         uint_ [ phx::ref(num) = _1 ] 
      >> 'X' 
      >> as_string [ lexeme[+graph] ] [ phx::ref(parsed_str) = _1 ],
      blank);
  ```

**All of this complexity can be hidden from your view if you avoid manual attribute propagation!**

Comment: Is there a clean solution to enforcing the `separated by one or more spaces` rule?  I have this so far: `uint_ >> +no_skip[' '] >> 'X' >> +no_skip[' '] >> lexeme[+graph]`.  Does it get any better than that?

Comment: @Arlen Mmm: there is [`distinct` in the Spirit repository](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/distinct.html). The other day someone asked me to fix his grammar up and I proposed a [quick and dirty oneliner that might give you an idea too](https://github.com/sehe/streampunk/commit/4c68c37de2a64d4836f931fb779a4f90298cb606). Hope that helps!

Comment: However, if whitespace is significant and you need to control the strict presence of it, I'd propose not using a skipper and spelling out the expected whitespace everywhere.